# How to hyphenate text in the a TextField in an RMarkdown fillable PDF?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr

I am creating a fillable PDF form in RMarkdown and have a TextField. Below is an example of my script-

```
---
title: Project Form
geometry: paperheight=11in,paperwidth=8.5in,margin=1in
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
      -    \usepackage[htt]{hyphenat}
urlcolor: blue   
---
\textcolor{DarkGreen}{Overview}
\
Program Title
\
*Provide the name of the program/project.*
\
\
\TextField[height = 3cm, width = 18 cm, bordercolor = {White}, color = {Red},multiline=true, align = 0]{ }
```

The resulting PDF does not hyphenate words instead it moves the whole word to the next line. Please see image for example.
[image]

I would like for it to look like:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.